# Basic Authentication for Google Cloud Stored Files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to store files on Google Cloud Storage and give devices access to the files via GET HTTP with basic authentication using username and password or something similar.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I will ask you a question to introduce my answer:

- If you set a login/password in the basic authentication, which system will validate them?

Cloud Storage relies only on OAuth token. Nothing built-in, you have to build your custom authentication mechanism.

So, you need an additional service that check the credential and then provide a link to download the file.

I recommend you to

- Create a serverless service, such as a [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs) or a [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs) services
- Perform a GET on it with your basic authentication to this service
- The service check the authentication, you can use [firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs) database to store the credential/permissions/autorisations of the connected user
- If the auth is OK, create a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) and return it with a 302 HTTP code (redirect)